# how to make web use firebase cloud function(express) + hosting + firestore

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm making website on firebase.

now my website is working.

but i don't know how to read firestore data and response with the data.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    admin.firestore().collection('post').get()
    .then(snap => {
        const data = snap.size;
        console.log("size: " + data);
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

log is work but not response.

```
RangeError: Invalid status code: 24
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/user_code/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:573:10)
    at ServerResponse.end (/user_code/node_modules/express-session/index.js:354:19)
    at ServerResponse.send (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10)
    at admin.firestore.collection.get.then.snap (/user_code/routes/main.js:14:26)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Actually, it's a QuerySnapshot in this case, and it does have a size property.

Answer (score 2):

`const data = snap.size` gives you a number type variable which is the size of the collect you just queried.  When you pass a number to send(), it looks like that tells Express you want to send that number as an HTTP status code to the client (and apparently it overrides what you set with status()).  The API docs for [send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) doesn't even say that you can pass a number.

If you want to send a number as the body of the response, try converting it to a string instead:

```
res.status(200).send('' + data);
```

Or bundle it up into a JSON object for the client to parse, which is probably better.